# iterate over asynchronous function synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a  function which reads data from oracle database, excel file and does some operations on the data and then stores the result data in an excel file.

```
const app = require('./index.js');
app('ZR_CUSTOMER_INVOICES Functional Specification')
```

```
const azureFunction = require('./connections/azureConnection');
const idsFunction = require('./connections/idsconnection');
const xlsFunction = require('./connections/readExcel');
const writeToExcel = require('./connections/writeToExcel');
var azureData;
var idsData;
var xlData;
var xlColumns;
var azureColumns;
var idsColumns;
var resultData;
var table_name;
var file_name='';
function app(fileName){
  file_name=fileName
  xlsFunction(file_name,xlCallback);
}
function xlCallback(xlresult,tName){
  table_name=tName;
  xlData=xlresult
  xlColumns=xlData.map((a,i)=>{
    return a.Columns
  })
  var azquery=`exec sp_columns  ${table_name}`
  azureFunction(azquery,acallback);
}
function acallback(azresult){
  // let table_name=xlData[0]['View Name']
  let idsquery=`select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name ='${table_name}')`;
  azureData=azresult;
  azureColumns=azureData.map((a,i)=>{
    return a.value
  })
  idsFunction(idsquery,icallback);
}
function icallback(idsresult){
  idsData=idsresult;
  idsColumns=idsresult.rows.map((a,i)=>{
    return a[0]
  })
  finalFunction()
}
function finalFunction(){
  resultData=xlData.map((a,i)=>{
    if(a.Columns==''){
      return;
    }
    a['inIds?']=idsColumns.includes(a.Columns);
    a['inAzure?']=azureColumns.includes(a.Columns);
    return a;
  })
  resultData=resultData.filter((a,i)=>{
    return a!==undefined;
  })
  // console.log(resultData);
  writeToExcel(resultData,file_name)
  console.log('done');
}

module.exports=app;
```

this is working fine.

but if I make function call to app twice.

```
const app = require('./index.js');
app('ZR_CUSTOMER_INVOICES Functional Specification')
app('ZR_CONTACTS Functional Specification')
```

I am getting output as done only once and then the control also doesn't break.

I think there is some problem with connections to database, so I want to do this synchronously and check.

//comment me if you need any code.

Comment: Where is the `async function` defined? I don't see any in the code above

Comment: @pete — It's asynchronous in the general sense, not in the "has the `async` keyword" sense.

Comment: "so I want to do this synchronously" — Async functions cannot be made syncronous.

Comment: Be careful when constructing SQL statements. Using a template literal as you're doing for `table_name` opens you up for SQL injection. Normally, I'd recommend using bind variables, but because tables are identifiers not values (like those stored in a table), you'll need to sanitize the `table_name` value to ensure it's safe. The easiest thing to do is to compare the value passed from the user against a set of known values that are okay to use.

Comment: @DanMcGhan thank you very much , I forgot about sql injection while writing the code.

Comment: @Quentin but you can control the flow of executions. what if you want fun2() to get executed after fun1() and you call both of them at the same time?? Using callback functions or using async-await would be the answer if it was javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using callbacks.

```
const azureFunction = require('./connections/azureConnection');
const idsFunction = require('./connections/idsconnection');
const xlsFunction = require('./connections/readExcel');
const writeToExcel = require('./connections/writeToExcel');
const done = require('./app');
var azureData;
var idsData;
var xlData;
var xlColumns;
var azureColumns;
var idsColumns;
var resultData;
var table_name;
var file_name='';
function app(fileName){
  file_name=fileName
  xlsFunction(file_name,xlCallback);
}
function xlCallback(xlresult,tName){
  table_name=tName;
  xlData=xlresult
  xlColumns=xlData.map((a,i)=>{
    return a.Columns
  })
  var azquery=`exec sp_columns  ${table_name}`
  azureFunction(azquery,acallback);
}
function acallback(azresult){
  // let table_name=xlData[0]['View Name']
  let idsquery=`select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name ='${table_name}')`;
  azureData=azresult;
  azureColumns=azureData.map((a,i)=>{
    return a.value
  })
  idsFunction(idsquery,icallback);
}
function icallback(idsresult){
  idsData=idsresult;
  idsColumns=idsresult.rows.map((a,i)=>{
    return a[0]
  })
  finalFunction()
}
function finalFunction(){
  resultData=xlData.map((a,i)=>{
    if(a.Columns==''){
      return;
    }
    a['inIds?']=idsColumns.includes(a.Columns);
    a['inAzure?']=azureColumns.includes(a.Columns);
    return a;
  })
  resultData=resultData.filter((a,i)=>{
    return a!==undefined;
  })
  // console.log(resultData);
  writeToExcel(resultData,file_name)
  console.log('done');
  done.onDone()
}

module.exports=app;
```

```
const app = require('./index.js');
app('ZR_CUSTOMER_INVOICES Functional Specification')
function onDone(){
    app('ZR_CONTACTS Functional Specification')
}
exports.onDone=onDone
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of variables (e.g. `var azureData;`) which are scoped to the module.

When you call the function twice, both sets of function calls will share those variables.

In particular, this means that `file_name=fileName` will set `file_name` to `'ZR_CUSTOMER_INVOICES Functional Specification'` and then to `'ZR_CONTACTS Functional Specification'`, and both calls will continue to use the variable with the value `'ZR_CONTACTS Functional Specification'`.

Define those variables **inside the scope of `app`**. Then define all the functions which need to access them inside of `app` too so that the variables are in scope for them.

Each call to `app` will then have its own set of variables and they won't overwrite each other.